# Display User Profile information from Membership .Net using MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, asp.net-membership

I am currently have a bunch of users sitting in a Membership Database and I want to be able to create a page in an MVC App that will be designed to pull back all the user information and display it on the page, I have created the solution below however I want be able to show the data in a Grid View instead of a list:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var systemUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
            return View(systemUsers);
        }
```

View:

```
 <ul>
        <%foreach (MembershipUser user in Model){ %>

        <li><%=user.UserName %></li>

        <% }%>
   </ul>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can get the users data and display it in a Grid View on the View? I was thinking that I could have a model that stores the data in which is then passed to the view and this model could be updated by the controller? But im unsure which datatype could be used to store the users data and then passed to the Grid View?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I just want to find some way of passing the "systemUsers" var to the Grid View?

Comment: Either strongly type the Model in your view, i.e. `@model IEnumerable<MembershipUser>`, or you could also just use ViewBag, e.g. `ViewBag.Users = systemUsers;` on the controller and then use this in the view. But I would suggest looking at ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

Using `MembershipUser` directly in your views isn't a very pure MVC approach, IMO.

IMO you could create a specific ViewModel containing just the fields you need to pass between the controller and the view, like so:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    // etc
}
```

After fetching all your users in your controller, you can then project the MembershipUsers across to your UserViewModel objects, e.g. using LINQ or AutoMapper, and then pass this enumeration into the View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var systemUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();       
    var vmUsers = new List<UserViewModel>();
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        vmUsers.Add(new UserViewModel()
        {
            UserId = (Guid)u.ProviderUserKey,
            UserName = u.UserName,
           // etc
        });
    }
    return View(vmUsers);
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'GridView' (this is MVC, not WebForms), but the [MVC WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) should do fine:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyNamespace.UserViewModel>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Obviously you'll want to tweak the look and feel a bit.

Comment: I Just tried -- var users = new List(); 
            systemUsers.ForEach(u => users.Add(new UserInfoModel() { UserId = u.UserId, UserName = u.UserName}));

Comment: However the app does not recognise "List()" and also says the var I have(systemUsers) doesnt have a method called "ForEach"

Comment: @user723858 - Apologies - I've updated the code - a `foreach` will do just as well.

Comment: Thanks :-)
I have updated the solution as you need to made the objects in the model public so they are accessible within the view. However it still says that "Unknown member 'UserName' of 'object'" and the same for "UserId", any ideas hwta could be causing this?

Comment: @user723858 - oops - the properties need to be public as well.

Comment: When you say I need to change the properties to be public where is this done?

Comment: @user723858 - I've fixed - the UserId field isn't actually exposed directly (but if you are using the default Membership provider you can cast the ProviderUserKey to Guid). My apologies

Comment: Thanks for all the help however I am getting this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.UserViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyNameSpace.UserViewModel'.

Comment: @user723858 Make sure that you have a collection defined as your strong Model type in your view (1st line) (Replace hash with at - so doesn't like) #model *IEnumerable<MyNamespace.UserViewModel>* or *ICollection<MyNamespace.UserViewModel>* or *IList<MyNamespace.UserViewModel>*

Comment: Hi thanks for all the help I have tried all 3: @model IEnumerable<MyNamespace.UserViewModel>  @model IList<MyNamespace.UserViewModel>  @model ICollection<MyNamespace.UserViewModel> and I still get the error when accessing the page: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.UserViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyNameSpace.UserViewModel'. This seems to happen no matter if I use a Collection List or IEnumerable

Comment: here is my inherits statement which if that helps :-)  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNameSpace.UserViewModel>

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how to do this, it must be easier than this??